# MySQL - Similar headings - multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, one containing the main information with a second table containing the same fields plus additional. The second table would have data which should overwrite the first table when queried. The fields are bigger, I've just shortened them down to show here.

First table (products):

```
+----+--------------+--------------+---------------+--------------------------+
| id | manufacturer | product_name | product_title |      product_description |
+----+--------------+--------------+---------------+--------------------------+
|  1 |     testingA |     productA | productTitleA | main product description |
|  2 |     testingA |     productB | productTitleB | main product description |
|  3 |     testingA |     productC | productTitleC | main product description |
+----+--------------+--------------+---------------+--------------------------+
```

Second Table (products_secondary)

```
+----+------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+----------------------+---------+
| id | product_id | manufacturer | product_name | product_title |  product_description | context |
+----+------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+----------------------+---------+
|  1 |          1 |       (null) |       (null) |        (null) | new description here |    test |
+----+------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+----------------------+---------+
```

My aim is to select the values from the second table where `context = text`

Expected result:

```
+----+--------------+--------------+---------------+--------------------------+
| id | manufacturer | product_name | product_title |      product_description |
+----+--------------+--------------+---------------+--------------------------+
|  1 |     testingA |     productA | productTitleA | new description here     |
|  2 |     testingA |     productB | productTitleB | main product description |
|  3 |     testingA |     productC | productTitleC | main product description |
+----+--------------+--------------+---------------+--------------------------+
```

The query which I know works is the following:

```
SELECT IFNULL(`products_secondary`.`product_description` , `products`.`product_description`) AS `product_description`
FROM `products`
LEFT JOIN `products_secondary` ON `products_secondary`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` AND `products_secondary`.`context` = 'test'
```

I'm sure there is an easier way to do this than having to supply IFNULL() for each field. Here is an SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6985b/1

Thanks.

Comment: Thats a terrible database design. Why have all the columns from table 1 in table 2 anyway, but to have them all as NULL makes even less sence

Comment: @RiggsFolly It looks like the first table is defaults, the second table overrides the defaults. A more common application that uses this is translation tables, with a table of defaults when there's no translation.

Comment: I don't think there's any easier way than lots of `IFNULL` tests. Sorry.

Comment: With the current design, ifnulls or an equivalent case statement look like the only option.

Answer (score 1):

Use this query

```
SELECT a.id, a.manufacturer, a.product_name, a.product_title, IF(b.context IS NOT NULL, b.product_description, a.product_description) as product_description
FROM
    products a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN products_secondary b ON a.id=b.product_id
```

Comment: It may work in this particular example, but take note that this is an example of a defaults table, ie if there is no value for a field in the main table, take it from the defaults. Unfortunately, the right wayy to do it for the general case is the ifnulls.